# SQL: Constructing date with variable year, fixed month and day

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i want add parameter to select only year My parameter=  @P1 
but the month and day are fixed
my date `'2005-01-01 00:00:00.000' and '2005-12-31 00:00:00.000'`

```
    Declare @Date datetime
    set @Date= @P1
    --i want to show like this: 
  select '@P1-01-01 00:00:00.000'as[ start year] ,'@P1-12-31 00:00:00.000'as
  [End_Year] from TB1
```

Comment: Are you working with `date`s or with `datetime`s? If your data has a time component, it's almost always better to work with an inclusive start point and an *exclusive* end point. E.g. the range `2005-01-01 00:00:00.000` - `2005-12-31 00:00:00.000` would exclude a value of `2005-12-31 14:51:32.317`. Is that your intention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the year from your `DATE` value, then use string concatenation to make new dates.

```
DECLARE @year CHAR(4) = DATEPART(YEAR, @date)
SELECT @year + '-01-01' AS [start year], @year + '-12-31' AS [end year]
```

You don't need to include the time if they're all zeroes.

If you want them as real `date` or `datetime` types, use `CAST` or `CONVERT`

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, @year + '-01-01') AS [start year],
       CONVERT(DATE, @year + '-12-31') AS [end year]
```